# How to mixing run ruby and javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby

How to use ruby and javascript mixing?

For example:

```
<div>
    $(".pop-up-confirm").click( function(e) {
      var domain_name = $("input#domain_name")[0].value;
      var msg = #{call_ruby_function(domain_name)};
    }
</div>
```

First, I use js to get the value `domain_name` from input.
Second, I want call `ruby_function`, use `domain_name` as parameter.
The first step is correct, but I how to make the second correct.

Comment: Normally what you want to do is have some data attribute with some url and in javascript you would perform ajax request to that url. Response body would be your message.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute ruby in the browser. You can only execute javascript. You can either rewrite your function in javascript, or make a request to your ruby server.

Comment: You are right and I will make a request to ruby server. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue you should perform AJAX request.

```
$.get('/some-path', { domain: domain_name }, function(data) {
  # data is your message
});
```

Ruby code will be executed in server-side and your message should be returned to you to work with in client-side

My example requires jQuery to be available

Comment: This is now my way. Thank you for your help!